# Php (int) parse weird result explanation

Tags: php, parsing, integer

Why does this code:

```
echo (int)((0.1+0.7)*10);
```

Return 7?

Is this because of some weird approximation algorithm of math operations in php causing 0.1+0.7 to be almost 0.8 and not exact 0.8?

It confuses me because any other decimal value returns correct answer like with *0.1+0.8* and so on and so on.

Comment: Quite odd cause if you leave off the int casting the result is 8 as expected.